# Websocket Data Maximum

Tags: wcf, html, websocket

Hi I just wanted to know if there is a maximum value for the data transfer over WebSockets?
I am using Websockets to read a File from the Server and send it back to the client. But when I'm trying to read a big File (>60000Chars) the Websocket closes...
Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser and server. Also, are you getting an error from the browser (Javascript console, onerror event, or via the close message)?

Comment: Well I'm using IE9 and the Visual Studio Development Server 2010... But theres no error or something. The Websocket just closes with Websocket.Close(). And then it calls the Eventhandler OnClose()

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not support WebSockets natively so I'm going to assume you are using either Microsoft HTML5 Labs WebSocket experiment or the web-socket-js fallback/polyfill.

It would not surprise me at all if HTML5 labs WebSocket experiment and/or the web-socket-js cannot handle large frames. It's also possible that the server is fragmenting the frames and I'm fairly certain that web-socket-js does not support frame fragmentation and I wouldn't be surprised if the same is true of the HTML5 Labs WebSocket experiment.

If you are using web-socket-js, please file a bug (with specific details about your configuration) so that the issue can be resolved. If you are using the HTML5 Labs experiment then you might try IE10 and if it is a problem there too then report the bug the bug to Microsoft.